Why has the 'drag down to copy' option disappeared in grid view on a custom SharePoint list?
I'm working in a SharePoint list, and previously when editing in grid view, I was given a small node on the bottom right of each cell to drag and copy the data to an adjacent cell (similar to MS excel) - for some reason this option has disappeared, and I cannot figure out why or how to get it back. Some of our list has data that applies across multiple entries (eg: we have several people who work at the same company, all of the information in the cells associated with 'business address'), and being able to drag and copy this information sped things up massively!
Thanks a lot for any suggestions / input!

Make sure you are not grouping by any columns when you enter Edit in Grid View. View the list as All Items.
